# Django: Avg, Max and Min of count of M2M field

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have the models:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(blank=True)
    keywords = models.ManyToManyField(Keyword, null=True, blank=True)

class Keyword(models.Model):
    keyword = models.CharField(max_length=155, blank=True)
```

I want to calculate the average, minimum and maximum count of M2M relations for all Articles.
I am a bit lost here. Can anybody help?

Comment: I don't think this is possible using only Django ORM and no raw sql. I think writing your own query or using python code are the only solutions here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Count, Max, Min, Avg

Article.objects.annotate(
    keywords_count=Count('keywords')
).aggregate(
    keywords_count_max=Max('keywords_count'),
    keywords_count_min=Min('keywords_count'),
    keywords_count_avg=Avg('keywords_count')
)
# or
Article.objects.annotate(Count('keywords')).aggregate(
    Max('keywords__count'), Min('keywords__count'), Avg('keywords__count'))
```

This should return dict `{'keywords_count_max': ..., 'keywords_count_min': ..., 'keywords_count_avg': ...}` in first case and `{'keywords__count__max': ..., 'keywords__count__min': ..., 'keywords__count__avg': ...}` in second case. Documentation has [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregating-annotations).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Works very good. BTW I was consulting the documentation, but I could not figure it out.